# Getting segmentation fault due to strlen()

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, mips64

My application crashes randomly with the below backtrace not getting any clue what can lead to segmentation. I will post the code also if required.

**Backtrace:**

```
 StackDump : 3116
 :3116: 0 /usr/sbin/appl/sharedobj/liblibLite.so(_Z9dumpStackb+0x650) [0xffef12ac58]
 :3116: 1 /usr/sbin/appl/sharedobj/libdebugFrameWork.so(_Z15sigsegv_handleriP9siginfo_tPv+0x300)[0xffef6144b0]
 :3116: 2 [0xfffffff010]
 :3116: 3 /lib64/libc.so.6(strlen+0x7e)[0xffed0badee]
 :3116: 4 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs6assignEPKc+0x30) [0xffed3e2550]
 :3116: 5 /usr/sbin/appl/app.d() [0x10979efc]
 :3116: 6 /usr/sbin/appl/app.d() [0x10980528]
 :3116: 7 /usr/sbin/appl/app.d(_ZN7Ems_gui15TunnelGroupPageER3EnvRSoRKN8security8eAccessTE+0x3b4) [0x1098af8c]
 :3116: 8 /usr/sbin/appl/app.d(_ZN6MethodclEP9WebServerR3EnvRSoRSiRKSslbl+0x460) [0x1062ae60]
 :3116: 9 /usr/sbin/appl/app.d(_ZN9WebServer13handleRequestI12SocketStreamEEvPT_+0x1b7c) [0x106403ac]
 :3116: 10/usr/sbin/appl/app.d(_Z16theHandleRequestPv+0x154) [0x10634e2c]
 :3116: 11/usr/sbin/appl/sharedobj/liblibLite.so(_ZN13threadElement11runFunctionEv+0x94) [0xffef17783c]
 :3116: 12 /usr/sbin/appl/sharedobj/liblibLite.so(_Z19interimCallBackFuncPv+0x30) [0xffef1778d8]
 :3116: 13 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xb9ec) [0xffef06c9ec]
 :3116: 14 /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x10ba4c) [0xffed11ba4c]
```

**c++filt Output:**

```
$ c++filt _ZNSs6assignEPKc
$ std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)
```

**Code Snippet which is getting called as per the crash analysis:**

```
string oper = cgi.get("Submit");
string inst = cgi.get("inst");
string parent = cgi.get("parent");

Handle<ServiceSwitch> hss = DYNAMIC_CAST<Manageable, ServiceSwitch> (Manageable::getManageableByName (inst));

if (!hss) { return 0; }

if(oper.empty()) {
   view_SystemCfg(hss, os, userPrivilegeLevel);
} else if(oper == "Edit") {
   edit_SystemCfg(envp, os, userPrivilegeLevel);
 } else if(oper == "View_Entries"){
   viewFDBEntries_SystemCfg(hss, cgi, os, userPrivilegeLevel);
 }else {
   view_SystemCfg(hss, os, userPrivilegeLevel);
}
```

**Detailed StackTrace:**

```
ffef12ac58|app.d.map              |Not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ffef6144b0|app.d.map              |Not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fffffff010|app.d.map              |Not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ffed0badee|app.d.map              |Not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ffed3e2550|app.d.map              |Not found
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10979efc  |app.d.map              |Ems_gui::SystemCfgPage(Env&, std::ostream&,
security::eAccessT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10980528  |app.d.map              |Ems_gui::SystemCfgPage(Env&, std::ostream&,
security::eAccessT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1098af8c  |app.d.map              |Ems_gui::TunnelGroupPage(Env&, std::ostream&,
security::eAccessT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1062ae60  |app.d.map              |Method::operator()(WebServer*, Env&,
std::ostream&, std::istream&,
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
106403ac  |app.d.map              |void
WebServer::handleRequest<SocketStream>(SocketStream*) + 7036
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10634e2c  |app.d.map              |theHandleRequest(void*) + 340 instruction
opcodes
```

I have posted the code for the address at `[10979efc]` but as you can see from the code snippet not getting any clue.

Comment: Most likely due to the fact that the `const char*` buffer passed to `strlen` does not contain a NUL in the memory that you purportedly own.

Comment: But in that case it is an inner implementation of either empty() function call. which checks for if the string is empty or not. Where else did strlen get triggered from? Because I am not using it in my code directly.

Comment: Look closely at stack frames 7 to 10 for clues.

Comment: Hi David thanks for the reply but not getting any clue from the code. It will be great if you guys can help me resolve this issue.